# didReceiveRemoteNotification not called swift 3 iOS 10

Tags: swift, swift3, push-notification, ios10, appdelegate

I made a lot of search during many days (20 posts+) but I didn't the solution to my problem.

I have an application which receive push notification, **I can receive those remote notifications but** when I tap on it, the delegate "didReceiveRemoteNotification" is not called (I want to intercept the payload to do action in fonction of it).

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
    print("test")
}
```

In advance, thanks for help.

The didReceiveRemoteNotification method does not fire when the user launches the app by tapping on the notification and not when the notification is received, never.

*Sorry for my bad english and if you have question, don't hesitate.*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [didReceiveRemoteNotification not called , iOS 10](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39382852/didreceiveremotenotification-not-called-ios-10)

Comment: I have already tried the solutions on this post

Comment: If you want to handle the notification when it's delivered to the user? Use the UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate protocol methods

Comment: @Mannopson , I just added :

    @ available(iOS 10.0, *)
        func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @ escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
        print("test2")
    }


    @ available(iOS 10.0, *)
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @ escaping () -> Void) {
        print("test3")
    }


But nothing is called

Comment: Set the delegate to self and then works.

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/43647816/6680583

Comment: @Mannopson

I've already this code :

//create the notificationCenter
        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            let center  = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
            center.delegate = self
            // set the type as sound or badge
            center.requestAuthorization(options: [.sound,.alert,.badge]) { (granted, error) in
                // Enable or disable features based on authorization
                
            }
            application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
        } else {
            // Fallback on earlier versions
        }

Comment: Check the comment above

Comment: @Mannopson is your answer is for remote notification ? Because i think it's for LOCAL notification

Comment: It's works with the remote and local notifications

Comment: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/54332

Comment: Mannopson I tried your solution but willPresent and didReceive delegates still not called

@JigarTarsariya I saw this solution but can't test it because it was in Obj C, how can i do the same in Swift 3 please ?

Comment: @Nuccle This is not my solution:) It's an API and it's provided by Apple

Comment: @Nuccle.. Did u find any solution . I am still not getting notifications

Comment: @UmaMadhavi Yes problem solved, I had this line "UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self" in my first viewController, it created a conflict with the UNUserNotificationCenter which I declared in my appDelegate

Answer (score -2):

**First import UserNotification framework and then implement  UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate in ios10 to support push notification in ios10**

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
          //Handle notification tap
  }
```